# Openlayers not loading while using a django widget . What might be the error?

Tags: django

I am using a widget called floppyforms . `https://github.com/brutasse/django-floppyforms`

In an app called openmaps , my forms look like this

```
import floppyforms as forms

class GeoForm(forms.Form):
    point = forms.gis.PointField()
```

I think the widget is irrelevant of the view .

And my template looks like this

```
{# template.html #}
<html>
  <head>
    {{ form.media }}
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="/some-url/">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

what can be the error ? I am testing the widget here , so I am using the basic code provided by them , which is supposed to work .

I have included django.contrib.staticfiles . My django version is 1.3 .

Comment: I recently installed it successfully and might be able to assist you with a bit more info. What doesn't work? Is the response code ok, the HTML rendered, does the javascript give you errors, does it error when you submit the form? Firebug is your friend to help you find out...